# Can I get married and then still go visit to the USA on my same tourist visa I had before changing my maiden name and being married?

Tags: visas, usa, weddings, paraguay

I am a Paraguayan citizen who has visited the USA once four years ago. I am planning to obtain a tourist visa to go meet my fiancés family for two weeks in January. My fiancé is an American citizen. Then directly after our marriage in May we would like to go on a two-week honeymoon in the USA.

Will I still be able to use the same visa I had that I would use to go in January for the visit before we would be married or would I have to get a new one with my maiden name and marital status changed?

Basically I want to know what are my options.

Comment: Are you planning to stay in the US or just visit and leave?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use your old visa. You need to bring both passports AND evidence of name change, such as marriage certificate. Additionally if your evidence is not in English (i.e. Paraguay marriage certificate in Spanish), you need to bring a **certified** English translation.

See for example https://th.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/non-immigrant-visas-frequently-asked-questions (look at **If I already have a valid visa and I change my name (through marriage, or for other reasons), can I use my old visa?** question):

> Yes. As long as your passport is still valid for at least six months
>   beyond the date you plan on traveling, you may use your existing visa.
>   However, you should carry proof of your legal name change (i.e., the
>   Thai name change certificate with a certified English translation)
>   with you when you travel to the U.S. If you wish to reduce the
>   likelihood of encountering a delay at the port of entry, you are
>   welcome to apply for a new visa by following our normal application
>   procedures.

This of course is only relevant if your last name changes. If you keep your old last name, you can still use your visa and passport. Your marital status is not recorded on the US visa.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to my wife.  I am an American citizen. When we got married, she only had her Russian passport with a standard B1/B2 visa.  We got married in the USA.  After we returned to UK, she changed her passport and the new passport had her new surname.  The next time we went to the USA, she flew on her new passport, but carried her old passport with the visa with her - she had no problem boarding the flight and getting through the immigration in the USA.

So, the simple answer is, yes, you should still be able to travel on your existing visa, provided that (1) you have the physical passport with the visa (even if the passport is cancelled); and (2) that visa is still within the validity date and hasn't been cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what your passport states.

If your passport is the same (it carries your maiden name, the same as the visa) then you won't have any problems.

It will also depend if you are going on the same tourist visa; or if you'll be going as a spouse of an American citizen. If you'll use the same visitor visa, then you'll be okay.