# Can I still travel with an old passport with my maiden name to the U.S?

Tags: visas

I recently got married and I got my U.S visa last year. We are planning a trip to America and I have a new passport. Can I still travel with my old passport and visa under my maiden name with my new passport and marriage certificate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get married and then still go visit to the USA on my same tourist visa I had before changing my maiden name and being married?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54082/can-i-get-married-and-then-still-go-visit-to-the-usa-on-my-same-tourist-visa-i-h)

Comment: Is your old passport still valid? Can't you simply travel with it as if you were not married?

Answer (score 5):

Generally that should be fine. From [here](https://br.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/frequently-asked-questions-non-immigrant-visas/#:%7E:text=If%20your%20name%20has%20legally,and%20from%20the%20United%20States.)

> **I have a visa but it has my maiden/married name. Now I’m married/divorced, and my name has changed. Do I need a new visa?**

> If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel to and from the United States. If you have emergency travel that does not allow you time to get your visa updated, we recommend that when traveling, you carry a copy of the document showing the name change.

Note the word **"recommend"**. You should updated but it's ok to travel with the old one.